# Inlining HTML table cells in sentence

Tags: html, css, html-table

Is there a way to have HTML table cells inlined in the normal text flow with the text using CSS to make the text appear at the baseline of the surrounding text?

Simply making all table elements inline make the text shifted downwards as seen in the following example, which is undesirable.

```css
table,
table > tbody,
table > tbody > tr,
table > tbody > tr > td {
    display: inline;
}

table > tbody > tr > td {
     padding: 0px;
     margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 40em;">
  A table containing
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>possibly multiple cells</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>containing potentially a high amount of text that should not be shifted down</td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
  below the baseline.
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve what you're trying to do, you should add `vertical-align: baseline;` to each of the table elements in question.

Also, you don't need to target each of the elements with the hierarchy of ancestors. This should suffice:

```css
table,
tbody,
tr,
td {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 40em;">
  A table containing
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>possibly multiple cells</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>containing potentially a high amount of text that should not be shifted down</td>
      </tr>
    <tbody>
  </table>
  below the baseline.
</div>
```

Comment: Also I removed the margin rule because it wasn't doing anything. Table elements don't have any margin by default (at least not in chrome).

Comment: Thank you! I completely overlooked that `baseline` property value.

Comment: And regarding the margin rule: I add it in general pairwise to a padding rule to avoid thinking whether or not one of those two is set, in cases is is nevertheless undesired. But indeed, it could be superfluous.